# How to looping trough an array of object when array name is not consistent?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, foreach

Consider below example:

```
const obj ={
price:[{multiple items},{multiple items}],
name:"",
id:"",
}
```

i want to apply foreach on price property but the issue is the property name is changing wrt cases like saleprice , taxprice etc.

if i am using obj.keys() method it doesn't work because it returns key as a string.

Comment: Why does it matter if the key name is a string? If your question is about the array at the `price` property and how the objects within it can have different keys, don't you think it would be a good idea to show that in your example `obj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const obj = {
  price: [10, 20, 30],
  name: "",
  id: "",
};

const pricePropertyName = Object.keys(obj).find((prop) => prop.includes('price'));
if (pricePropertyName) {
  obj[pricePropertyName].forEach(el => {
    console.log(el);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const key = Object.keys(obj).find((key) => key.indexOf('price') > -1)
obj[key].forEach(price => console.log(price))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Object.values()" or "Object.fromEntries()" to get the values or both keys & values.

```
const obj ={
price:[{multiple items},{multiple items}],
name:"",
id:"",
}

const priceArray = Object.values(obj).find( value => Array.isArray(value))
```

FYI

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values